# Cannot access my AWS Lightsail Django application from public IP

Tags: django, ubuntu, deployment, virtualhost, amazon-lightsail

I am trying to host my Django application from my aws lightsail public IP. I have deployed my application to folder: /opt/bitnami/projects/spirit/spirit. and defined and activated the virtual host at  /etc/apache2/sites-available/spirit-vhosts.conf. My spirit-vhosts.conf file is:

```
<IfDefine !IS_spirit_LOADED>
  Define IS_spirit_LOADED
  WSGIDaemonProcess sample python-home=/opt/bitnami/python python-path=/opt/bitnami/projects/spirit processes=2 threads=1
5
</IfDefine>
<VirtualHost 127.0.0.1:80 _default_:80>
  ServerAlias *
  WSGIProcessGroup spirit
  Alias /robots.txt /opt/bitnami/projects/spirit/static/robots.txt
  Alias /favicon.ico /opt/bitnami/projects/spirit/static/favicon.ico
  Alias /static/ /opt/bitnami/projects/spirit/static/
  <Directory /opt/bitnami/projects/spirit/static>
    Require all granted
  </Directory>
  Alias /media/ /opt/bitnami/projects/spirit/media/
  <Directory /opt/bitnami/projects/spirit/media>
    Require all granted
  </Directory>
  WSGIScriptAlias / /opt/bitnami/projects/spirit/spirit/wsgi.py
  <Directory /opt/bitnami/projects/spirit/spirit>
    <Files wsgi.py>
      Require all granted
    </Files>
  </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

However, i cannot access my website from public IP. I have also added port 8000 as custom TCP in my aws lightsail network rules. When i perform `sudo wget 127.0.0.1:80` i do get the correct response in an html file. What am i missing?

Comment: I have used this as a reference for my app deployment: https://docs.bitnami.com/aws/infrastructure/django/get-started/deploy-django-project/
using the Approach A

Answer (score 1):

The IP you are trying to connect to is a localhost and not public. When you create your instance in the AWS console you will see a public dns name which you will be able to connect to.